# How to use typescript in web programming?

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js, typescript-typings

I am using `express` as a server. Simple project is:

```
.
├── src
│   └── index.html
│   └── index.ts
│   └── three.js
├── main.ts
├── package.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

where `main.js` is:

```
import * as express from 'express'

const app = express()

app.use(express.static('src'))

app.listen(80)
```

And where `index.html` is HTML file with only `<title>` tag in `<head>` and absolutely empty `<body>` tag after which I placed two `<script>` tags:

```
<script src='three.js'></script>
<script src='index.js'></script>
```

`three.js` is a library, which I want to use with typescript typings. I don't understand, how should I setup my `tsconfig.json` file to run

```
$ tsc --project tsconfig.json && node main.js
```

And get working result. One of questions - how should I include `three.js` typings into my `index.ts` file?

Answer (score 0):

First create a custom `./src/index.d.ts`.

> Side note: The name doesn't matter, as long as it ends in `.ts`, it's fine. Conventionally people pick names like, `index.d.ts`, `global.d.ts` or `types.d.ts` for such file. I don't want you to think `index.d.ts` has any matching relationship to `index.ts`, so to clarify.

I'm using `"three@0.120.1"`, the corresponding declaration file can be seen here: [Three.d.ts](https://unpkg.com/browse/three@0.120.1/src/Three.d.ts), make sure we're on same page.

Now put following content in the file:

```
/// <reference types="three" />

declare var THREE: typeof THREE;
```

And you're good to go. Try refer to `THREE` directly in `src/index.ts`, no error would be raised.

#### Explanation

`"three"` lib declare itself to be a UMD module. UMD module are very flexible, it can be consumed in multiple styles. You choose to expose `THREE` as global variable, by including `<script src='three.js' />` in HTML, instead of `import/require` mechanism.

However, from TS engine's view, it's still a *module*, it's unaware of the `<script src='three.js' />` thing. So you need to inform the TS engine that piece of information.

That's what the seemingly repetitive `declare var THREE: typeof THREE;` does.